# How can I delete a ec2 instance from EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I created a EKS cluster in AWS with 2 ec2 instances as node. Later I created a nodegroup with a required size as 3. Now I have 5 ec2 instances running, the 2 initial ones and the 3 from nodegroup. I am planning to use nodegroup to manage all nodes and I'd like to delete the 2 ec2 instances. The question is how I can delete them.

I tried to delete them from `kubectl delete node` command then terminate the ec2 instances from AWS console. But another two instances are launched automaticaclly. I believe the cluster still manages the two old ec2 instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an [Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html) managing those instances.

You need to [`kubectl drain`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/) your nodes, then delete the Auto Scaling Group to terminate the instances. Once it's done, `kubectl delete` the nodes.

You also may have a Cloud Formation configuration for managing these instances and their required resources. If so, consider deleting this configuration.

Comment: you might need the option "--ignore-daemonsets" to force draining off the host